# How does cluster_label_prop create groups?

Tags: r, visualization, data-visualization

I am trying to create a network plot using the following code:

```
clp <- cluster_label_prop(net)
class(clp)

plot(clp, net)
```

The output for clp shows 4 different groups, like below:

IGRAPH clustering label propagation, groups: 4, mod: 0.6
+ groups:

```
$`1`
  [1] "s01" "s02" "s03" "s04" "s05" "s11" "s15"

  $`2`
  [1] "s06" "s16" "s17"

  $`3`
  [1] "s07" "s08" "s09" "s10"

  $`4`
  + ... omitted several groups/vertices
```

However, when I run the same code on my own data, it only shows one group:

IGRAPH clustering label propagation, groups: 1, mod: 0
+ groups:

```
$`1`
   [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
  [34] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

Does anyone know how cluster_label_prop groups vertices?

Comment: You should add `library(igraph)` to your question code (otherwise, the function `cluster_label_prop` is not present). Could you include an example of your own data as well as the `net` object?

Comment: There are two questions. The first one you should check out the documentation (e.g. [here](http://igraph.org/r/doc/cluster_label_prop.html)). For the second one, your data doesn't appear to support more than one group (given your algorithm).